# Reduce duplication of elements while adding same classname

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a simpler way to reduce the number of times I adda class to an element?

Example code:

```
if (display.hasAttribute("homepage-events")) {
  startDate.classList.add('h6');
  endDate.classList.add('h6');
  startTime.classList.add('h6');
  endTime.classList.add('h6');
  dateContainer.classList.add('mb-2');
  timeContainer.classList.add('mb-2');

  title.classList.add('h5');
  location.classList.add('h6');
  
  item.classList.add('no-pad-top');
  columnLeft.classList.remove('col-md-3');
  columnRight.classList.remove('col-md-9');
  columnLeft.classList.add('col-md-12');
  columnRight.classList.add('col-md-12');
}
```

Can these be combined using vanilla js?

```
startDate.classList.add('h6');
endDate.classList.add('h6');
startTime.classList.add('h6');
endTime.classList.add('h6');
```

Comment: Could you please explain the expected output/purpose in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple helper function:

```
function addClass(className, elements) {
    elements.forEach(function (element) {
        element.classList.add(className); 
    });
}
```

Then use it:

```
addClass('h6', [startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime]);
```

If you are able to target newer syntax, you can write the helper function like this:

```
function addClass(className, elements) {
    for (let element of elements) {
        element.classList.add(className);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them in an array and run a loop.

```js
var h6Elements = [startDate, endDate, startTime, endTime]

h6Elements.forEach( e => e.classList.add('h6'))
```